# Remove special Unicode characters from a Java String

Tags: java, string, unicode

I am converting HTML data (data with bullet styling) to Java String, but we are getting junk values (`��` - default Unicode value replaced) in the String, I tried to remove these values using `replaceAll()` but it's not working.

Any suggestions about how to remove these Unicode characters from the String?

Comment: First, try to find out what the real chars those are, then just use `s = s.replace("the_chars", "")`.

Comment: Perhaps the better solution would be to treat encodings correctly so those characters are preserved as they should be, instead of removing them?

Comment: My html data has bullet styls , these style replaced with default unicode value(?) while converted to string in java.

Comment: You can check if it is defined. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Comment: @Balu, you've said as much (i.e. nearly nothing) in your question already. deceze noted that getting your encodings right from the start would prevent this problem from appearing by giving you the correct characters, _without_ the need of mangling your text afterwards even worse to get rid of the perceived problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all non-ASCII characters with:

```
s.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "")
```